# disappearing label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, client-side-validation

When an input doesn't pass validation, an **error label** appears after the input but **the first label** that holds inputs name disappears. Any ideas? Thanks.

**before validation**

```
<div class="field">
 <label class="default-label" for="user_email">Email</label>
 <input class="default-input" id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="email" value="" />
</div>
```

**after validation**

```
<div class="field">
 <div class="field_with_errors">
  <input class="default-input" id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="email" value="" />
  <label for="user_email" class="message">has already been taken</label>
 </div>
</div
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @user, :validate => true, :url => users_path, :method => :post do |f| %>

 <div class="field"><%= f.label :email,  { :class => "default-label" } %>
 <%= f.text_field :email,  { :class => "default-input" }  %></div>

 <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Go!", :class => "default-button" %></div>

<% end %>
```

**initializers/client_side_validations.rb**

```
require 'client_side_validations/simple_form' if defined?(::SimpleForm)
require 'client_side_validations/formtastic'  if defined?(::Formtastic)

ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  unless html_tag =~ /^<label/
    %{<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}<label for="#{instance.send(:tag_id)}" class="message">#{instance.error_message.first}</label></div>}.html_safe
  else
    %{<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}</div>}.html_safe
  end
end
```

**Gems**

- rails 3.1.0
- client_side_validations 3.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue in my project and I  found [this issue](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/985) on the github repository

I used [the fork proposed there](https://github.com/halida/rails_admin) and everything worked fine.